# Some applications are no longer launchable, due to their format being incorrect

Tags: macos

Recently some applications have started failing to open when double clicked.  I rebooted into the rescue OS, repaired my FS (no errors that I could see) and booted back into the latest Mavericks.  I redownloaded apps that wouldn't start, but now I see that Preview has ... changed / become corrupted?

[image: You can't open the application "Preview" because it is not supported on this type of Mac]

Can't open for the command line either:

```
$ open public/missing.png  -a Preview.app
The application /Applications/Preview.app cannot be opened because it has an incorrect executable format.
```

Any idea (1) what caused this and (2) how to I fix it? I'd rather not reinstall Mac OSX if I can help it.

I'm running the latest Mavericks on Mid 2012 MBPr.

Comment: Is `/Applications` linked to a different disk or partition?

Comment: If you don't want to do a clean reinstall, you can also [do an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763). It keeps user files and settings in place and it takes about an hour if you have a fast internet connection.

Comment: @Kent  - nope only one disk - the internal SSD.

Comment: @Lri - Interesting. Even if I'm already up to date? I guess I'll find out. Thanks.

Comment: @dkam Yeah. Apple calls it just reinstalling OS X, but they should come up with a better name for it, because it is more like repairing the current installation. I have done it twice so far and it fixed multiple issues both times.